# How to accurately round half up with tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to replicate some C++ based code into Python API of Tensorflow, but I'm having few floating point inaccuracy issues, although I have been able to find one of them.

Generally, Tensorflow seems to round decimals in a [round half down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_down) manner, meaning that if we have an integer with fractional value exactly equal to `0.5`, the integral part of that decimal will be rounded down to zero:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.Session().run(tf.math.round(2.5))
2.0
```

whereas, many imperative programming languages that I've encountered do the rounding in a [round half up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) manner. Some of these programming languages are [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) and [Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/round).

In fact, considering that Tensorflow was mostly written in C++, Python and Cuda C++, it seems like a weird convention for them to  be using `rounding half down` method for their functions in API.

---

**Question**:

Is there any neat way to implement a rounding function that utilizes `rounding half up` method instead of `rounding half down`?

The simplest function I could implement uses `tf.floormod` method:

```
>>> def classical_round(x): return tf.cond(tf.math.equal(tf.floormod(x, 1), tf.constant(0.5)), lambda: tf.math.ceil(x), lambda: tf.math.round(x))
...
>>> tf.Session().run(classical_round(4.5))
5.0
>>> tf.Session().run(classical_round(4.49))
4.0
>>> tf.Session().run(classical_round(4.49999999999999))
5.0
>>> tf.Session().run(classical_round(3.2))
3.0
```

Is this sufficiently accurate method? or can something similar be done by using other tensorflow operations?

**Research**:

I could only find [this Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3730) relevant to my problem, I think they ended up adding `tf.math.rint` for which I couldn't find the place in this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for the reference, but I'm looking for tensorflow equivalent of normal C++ round function, since the library that I'm trying to replicate has C++ code is already compiled (I want to avoid modifying library).

Comment: C++" is rarely "round decimals in a round half down", but round to nearest, ties to even.  Do not assume typical C++ FP rounding mode is  as `round()`.  IOWs, the goal of  "neat way to implement a rounding function that utilizes rounding half up method instead of rounding half down" may be misguided as the goal more likely should be "neat way to implement a rounding function that utilizes rounding like done in C++".  The "I'm having few floating point inaccuracy issues" is more complex than the conclusion about rounding modes.  Post code and data example. [mcve]

Comment: ShellRox Would you expect `rounding half up(-1.5)` to be _up_ to -1 or do you want `rounding half  way away from zero(-1.5)` to -2?

Comment: @chux I apologize to late response, I'm talking about `rounding half up` which has definition on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up . The code that I have presented above simply rounds half up (ceil division) if the fractional part of an decimal is exactly equal to 0.5, otherwise it performs classical rounding (floor if less than 0.5 and ceil if more than 0.5).

Answer (score 3):

called bankers rounding nothing wrong about that same thing happening in c# too. you can try something like that:

```
def classical_round(x):
    return tf.math.floor(x+0.5)

sess.run(classical_round(2.5)) #3.0
```

more information here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: This approach fails to round as desired for various `double` when the addition `x+0.5` itself incurs rounding before calling the function.  Candidates includes whole number values in the [2^53... 2^54] range and the FP values just smaller than +/- 0,5, 1.0.